# Covering unit square

Tags: computer-science, discrete-geometry, packing-problem, open-problem

Now, I am reading this topic https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles. And do some research on it. Guys, who had written in topics, have said, that they have implementations of algorithms, that cant cover 10.000 rectangles. But I can't find implementation. Can anyone help with that

Comment: Why not to add the comment there ??

Comment: @mvw I have been asking them by email 2-3 three times during last two weeks, but they have not answered yet, so I thought to ask here.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1505127/fractional-oblongs-in-unit-square-via-the-paulhus-packing-technique